# Не могу в задаче корректно вывести итоговый список( 5 и 3 нужно удалить)

Tags: python

```
main_list = [1, 5, 3]
first_side = [1, 5, 1, 5]
second_side = [1, 3, 1, 5, 3, 3]
for a in first_side:
  main_list.append(a)
print('Количество цифр 5 при первом объединении:', main_list.count(5))
for b in second_side:
  main_list.append(b)
print('Кол-во цифр 3 при втором объединении:', main_list.count(3))
print('Итоговый список: ', main_list.remove(a)
```

Comment: 5 и 3 нужно удалить уже после объединения? Все 5 и 3 нужно удалить или только одну 5 и одну 3? Или из изначального списка удалить 5 и 3? Или не учитывать 5 и 3 в изначальном списке? Что-то я вообще не понимаю, есть текст задачи?

Comment: Программа добавляет элементы побочного списка ‘b’ в основной, а затем считает количество цифр 5. Это число выводится на экран, и после этого цифры 5 удаляются из основного списка. Затем программа добавляет в основной список элементы списка ‘c’, считает количество цифр 3 и выводит это число на экран. В конце появляется и сам список.

Comment: Почитайте, что делает remove(). И вообще всегда читайте описание функции перед её использованием.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вас правильно понял:

```
main_list = [1, 5, 3]
first_side = [1, 5, 1, 5]
second_side = [1, 3, 1, 5, 3, 3]

# Добавляем элементы из списка "b" в основной список
for b in first_side:
    main_list.append(b)

five = main_list.count(5) 
print('Количество цифр 5 при первом объединении:', five)

# Новый основной список без цифр 5 
main_list = [num for num in main_list if num != 5]

# Как вариант, крутим цикл пока в списке есть цифра 5:
#while 5 in main_list: # Если очень хочется удалить через remove()
#    main_list.remove(5)

# Добавляем элементы из списка "c" в основной список
for c in second_side:
    main_list.append(c)

three = main_list.count(3) 
print('Количество цифр 3 при втором объединении:', three)

print('Итоговый список:', main_list)
```

Вывод консоли:

```
Количество цифр 5 при первом объединении: 3 
Количество цифр 3 при втором объединении: 4 
Итоговый список: [1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 5, 3, 3]
```

Comment: При слиянии списков явный цикл не требуется: `main_list.extend(first_side)` или `main_list += first_side`

Comment: Спасибо большое, разобралась